# CustomView overriding onTouch() and setting additional GestureDetector via setOnTouchListener()

Tags: android, android-custom-view, gesturedetector

Is it possible to create custom view that both overrides function `onTouch()` inside this custom view implementation, and enables to set custom GestureDetector via `setOnTouchListener()`.

1. I would like to Override onTouch() method to implement some drawing logic in the View related to touch gestures.
2. Than I would like to use such self-contained custom view to attach to it GestureDetector to detect and handle some custom gestures on this view inside Activity.

It works for me only if I have onTouch() drawing implementation, or only setOnTouchListener() to detect gestures. Maybe I could place this gesture detection inside view. But I would prefer to have this as separate loosely coupled reusable component rather than tightly coupled gesture detector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do somethink like this:

```
public class CustomTouchView extends View {

    private OnTouchListener onTouchListener;

    public CustomTouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener l) {
        super.setOnTouchListener(l);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (onTouchListener != null) {
            return onTouchListener.onTouch(this, event);
        } else {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        // or implement your custom touch logic here 
    }
}
```

Comment: This lead me to some solution I think. I have used in CustomTouchView() constructor setOnTouchListener(this) and implement onTouch(). So I instead make custom private field TouchViewGestureDetector, and add setter method setTouchViewGestureDetector(detector). Then inside onTouch override in CustomTouchView, I have added if(mGestureDetector != null) mGestureDetector.onTouch(event);

Comment: @MichałZiobro feel free to mark my answer if it helped you. Thanks